# How to stream video from a Raspberry Pi to Elixir and to the web

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, html5-video, elixir

I'm trying to stream high-quality live video from a Raspberry Pi 3+camera module.  I want to public the stream on a public webpage (using video.js I think).  I also want an elixir server (on the same LAN as the Pi) to consume the stream to detect faces and motion in it.  I am a video streaming noob.

What's the best way to do this?  Specifically:

1. What transport mechanism should I use on the Pi?  RTP?  WebRTC? <sup>*Is that even* <sup>*a transport mechanism?*</sup></sup>
2. How do I pull images out of a (whatever transport mechanism I used above) stream in Elixir?  Is there a library that does it?
3. If I want to support more simultaneous users than the Pi can handle, what's the right way to proxy the stream through Phoenix?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [Evercam project](https://github.com/evercam/evercam-server)

Comment: Thanks @Sheharyar, their code looks like much more than what I need, so I gave them a shout with an offer to help carve out a library.